# Software-based audio service

Tags: windows-7, audio

I'm working with an app that's responsible for recording the default windows audio device on a box that does not have audio hardware - it's a dedicated server located at our web-host. Is it possible to simulate a windows audio device with software alone so that the app finds something to record to?

thx

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an audio device, many of the supporting services and drives won't even be loaded, so your application can definitely not produce a sound.

Total Recorder among others will install a virtual audio device (driver level) for capturing all system sound, so you can use that.

If your web host does not allow you to install drivers (unlikely for dedicated machines), you can always run a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'software alone' you mean on the application level, then no.

You'd have to come up with a device driver to simulate the audio hardware.

I doubt your web host will let you install drivers, but if they're hosting it from Windows 7 (as your tag suggests) you never know. ;)